# Sqoop on EMR-4.x deprecated error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sqoop, emr

I am getting data from Sqoop, It's run in aws successfully in EMR 3X version resource: http://rohitghatol.com/?p=699 , but If i run same script in latest version EMR 4.x it gets this error.

I have used s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar as a jar and sqoop script : s3://bucket/sqoopscript.sh as a argument.
New command command-runner.jar, but it required main class, but there is no any main class in sqoop script. How to run this script in aws emr-4.x?

Error:

`Note: /tmp/sqoop-hadoop/compile/fc96c9a73480a352c59115a221d66f72/QueryResult.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Command exiting with ret '1'`

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop is now available on emr-4.4.0 as a normal applicaiton launchable via the console, SDK, and CLI.